# how to call ajax request one time to load data in multiple component instances

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my vue project, I have a component which will load data via ajax request. The view page will use this component 3 times, and the request parameters and result are totally same. I want the ajax request be called only 1 time. what's the best practice? I understand use the vuex store or session storage to save the ajax result in the component can do it, but is there any better idea?

jsfiddle link: [jsfiddle.net/cqli/5g7anu0f/37](https://jsfiddle.net/cqli/5g7anu0f/37)

Template:

```html
<div id="app">
    <show-title></show-title>
    <show-title></show-title>
    <show-title></show-title>
</div>
```

Component definition:

```js
    Vue.component('show-title', {
        mounted(){
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => this.title = json.title);
      },
        data: function () {
        return {
          title: "hello world!"
        }
      },
      template:"<h3>{{title}}</h3>"
    });
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
      },
      methods: {
      }
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

They'll be the same, because you calling URL with same data: `id = 1`. You need to use props for your component:

```js
Vue.component('show-title', {
    props: ['id'], // here you defined props
    mounted(){
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'+this.id) // here you fetch todo with ID from props.
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => this.title = json.title);
  },
    data: function () {
    return {
      title: "hello world!"
    }
  },
  template:"<h3>{{title}}</h3>"
});
```

In your template add `:id`:

```
<show-title :id="1"></show-title>
<show-title :id="2"></show-title>
<show-title :id="3"></show-title>
```

Comment: The calling URL and response data are totally same in 3 times ajax, it's what I expect, so I want to call it only one time for 3 component instances on one page, because the response data is same. I need put the fetch method in my component, but I don't want call it multiple times on one page.

Comment: if so call fetch in parent and pass data by `prop` , it will execute one time @CQLI

Comment: @ﾃﾞﾋﾞｯﾄ yes, exactly. But I don't want to do it in parent, it's the component's job, shouldn't ask the person who use the component to handle it.

Comment: Yes you are right , it's component job so it have 3 and called 3 times :)